# How would I use DATEDIFF(), NOW(), and BETWEEN in a db_delete() query?

Tags: 7, database

Is the something like the following possible?

```
db_delete('note_dates')
    ->condition("DATEDIFF('start', NOW()) BETWEEN 0 AND 30")
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DeleteQuery::where()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/function/DeleteQuery%3A%3Awhere/7), e.g.

```
$args = array(':arg1' => $foo, ':arg2' => $bar);
db_delete('note_dates')
  ->where("DATEDIFF('start', NOW()) BETWEEN :arg1 AND :arg2", $args);
  ->execute();
```

That'll give you

```
DELETE FROM {note_dates} 
WHERE  (DATEDIFF('start', NOW()) BETWEEN :arg1 AND :arg2)
```